# Executing groovy script in java

Tags: java, groovy

I want to execute a groovy script in java and being new to both java and groovy i am having some problems. Just trying to learn.

```
import groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader;
import groovy.lang.GroovyObject;
import groovy.lang.GroovyShell;

import javax.naming.Binding;
import java.io.File;

public class envHealth extends GroovyShell{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            ClassLoader parent = envHealth.class.getClassLoader();
            GroovyClassLoader loader = new GroovyClassLoader(parent);
            Class groovyClass = loader.parseClass(new File("M://CheckEDWs.groovy"));

            GroovyObject groovyObject = (GroovyObject) groovyClass.newInstance();
            Object[] args1 = {};
            groovyObject.invokeMethod("run",args);

            System.out.println("Success");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
             System.out.println("Failed");
        }
    }

}
```

It fails with

> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/cli/ParseException

Comment: If it exits with "Failed", an exception was thrown. Print the stack trace. `e.printStacktrace()`

Comment: [NoClassDefFoundError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html)

Comment: please stop posting the same question over and over

Comment: possible duplicate of [Executing groovy file in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17807400/executing-groovy-file-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

You have missing dependencies. Add [Commons CLI](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/) to your classpath.